# composing mysql query for viewed notifications

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am writing a notification alert functionality. I have a a table `Notification` there is a field `Viewed`. The value of `Viewed` is `TINYINT`. When the user views the notification it is flipped to `1`. Then based on `Viewed` I display the notfications that are ready for the alert. Now in case there are no new er notification I want to display the recently viewed notification. the query I used is

```
$query="select * from notification where NotifierId=? and Viewed=0 order by
NotificationDate DESC ";
```

Now what I want to do is something like this in Pseudo language

```
Select Fields from notification where NotifierId=someid and Viewed=0 Incase 
there are new notifications but retreive the old as well Viewed=1 if the new
notifications are less than 10 ordered by date
```

please let me know if there is any way to do it. Thanks

Comment: The above is currently functional ... The new one I want is something I  can't compose. I am unable control to flow in sql for true and false.

Comment: Have.you.tried.to.write.the.query? Without any sort of table configuration, data or expected output we would only be speculating on what you're trying to do here. Perhaps setup a SQL Fiddle that we can manipulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be interested in something like this:

```
select
    *
from
    notification
where
    NotifierId=? and
    Viewed in (0, IF((select count(*) from notification where Viewed = 0)<10,1,0))
order by
    Viewed asc,
    NotificationDate desc
```

This will cause non-viewed notifications to all be on top sorted by date descending and then the viewed notifications will show by date descending.

I hope I was able to fully understand your question but if not then please let me know.

Comment: The `Viewed` field is important here if  not viewed. or say is `false`

Comment: The Viewed=0 notification needs to be on top not below.

Comment: @whatever Yes, ` Viewed asc` should be doing that. Is it not behaving properly for you?